# How do I catch data from api after looping it to DOM

Tags: javascript, arrays, api, loops, dom

I've created a global variable named `movieID` and I have a function called `generateSearch`  which gets data from API and then the `displayResults` function loops over the results and displays the data on DOM.

My goal is to insert an event listener which when you click on a specific title of movie (`#more-details`) the `movieID` variable will take the clicked movie's ID!

```js
//GLOBAL VARIABLES
let resultArr = [];
let movieID;

//EVENT LISTENER
submitBtn.addEventListener('click', generateSearch)

//GENERATE SEARCH DATA
async function generateSearch() {
    resultArr = []

    const result = await fetch(`${baseURL}${search}${userInput.value}${apiKey}`)
    const data = await result.json();

    //push data in array
    data.Search.forEach(element => {
        resultArr.push(element)
    })
    console.log(resultArr)

    displayResults()
}

//DISPLAY ON UI
function displayResults() {
    clearUI()
    resultArr.forEach(movie => {
        const markup = `
       
        <div class="results">
            <img src="${movie.Poster}" alt="Movie Poster">
            <ul>
                <a href="#" id="more-details"><li>${movie.Title}</li></a>
                <li>${capitalizeFirstLetter(movie.Type)}</li>
                <li>${movie.Year}</li>
                <li>${movie.imdbID}</li>
            </ul>
            </div>
            
    `
        resultUI.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', markup)

    })
    moviePage()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set an click handler to a given function:

```
<a href="#" id="more-details" onclick="onTitleClicked('${movie.imdbID}')">
```

and

```
function onTitleClicked(id) { 
     console.info('do here what you want. id:', id);     
}
```

Comment: If you have a lot of movie panels in the page then you should use laruiss solution to reduce the amount of click handlers.

Comment: Thank you! I tried a similar solution before but for some reason didn't work and now I see that I had a syntax mistake with the onclick=""... Thank you for your help! I got everything working now!

Answer (score 2):

You should try to avoid global variables. Here a solution with explanation in comments:

```
//EVENT LISTENER
submitBtn.addEventListener('click', event => generateSearch(event.target.value))
document.body.addEventListener('click', event => { // For every click...
    const clickedElement = event.target // Get the clicked element
    const movieId = clickedElement.dataset.movieId
    if (movieId) {
        // Do something with the movieId
        // ...
    }
})


//GENERATE SEARCH DATA
async function generateSearch(query) {
    const result = await fetch(`${baseURL}${search}${query}${apiKey}`)
    const data = await result.json();

    const nodes = getResultsAsArrayOfNodes(data.Search)

    //DISPLAY ON UI
    // searchResultElement should be a DOM node in which all the results will be appended
    searchResultElement.append(...nodes) // Append all the nodes (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append)
}

function getResultsAsArrayOfNodes(movies) {
    return movies.map(movie => { // For each movie...
        const node = document.createElement('div') // ...create a node..
        node.className = 'results'
        const markup = `
            <img src="${movie.Poster}" alt="Movie Poster">
            <ul>
                <!-- Create here an element with an id that contains the IMDB movie id -->
                <li><a href="#" data-movie-id="${movie.imdbID}">${movie.Title}</a></li>
                <li>${capitalizeFirstLetter(movie.Type)}</li>
                <li>${movie.Year}</li>
                <li>${movie.imdbID}</li>
            </ul>
        `
        node.innerHTML = markup // ...put the markup in the div.results node
        return node // return the node
    }) // Return the array of nodes
}
```

Comment: To avoid ids in html: You can use  data-movie-id="${movie.imdbID}" as html attribute. After this you have to change the logic from the answer above a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your variable is really global.

```
window.movieID = null;
```

Then you should be able to do this.

```
<a href="#" id="more-details" onclick="window.movieID = ${movie.imdbID}">
```

Comment: I've tried doing something similar but for some reason the onclick functions get called right after the loop is initiated and not when I'm clicking the title. When I'm logging the movieID variable I get undifiend